# How to perform Core data fetch request in background without freezing UI

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I have implemented Core data in my app. Every 30 seconds an API call is performed in background to update the database from JSON response. So when I parse and try to save the JSON response into my Core data I want to perform it in background. It shouldn't affect my UI. Currently when save is happening it blocks UI since managed Object context operations are performed on main thread. I have followed approach from [this](https://medium.com/soundwave-stories/core-data-cffe22efe716)  blog. [image]

Sometimes crashes randomly with below logs :

```
Fatal Exception: NSGenericException
*** Collection <__NSCFSet: 0x283e6a220> was mutated while being enumerated.
```

Comment: The error means that the elements in a collection have been changed while looping through that collection. I'm sure someone can help, but you'd have to edit your question with the relevant code. One thing to bear in mind - that blog post is quite old - setting up the CoreData stack manually hasn't been necessary since iOS 10. First off, you should take a look at the Apple docs and make sure you get the CoreData stack set up correctly. The `NSPersistentContainer` class does the set up for you. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/setting_up_a_core_data_stack

Answer (score 3):

First we have a correctly configured CoreData stack:

```
    container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "UserData")
    container.persistentStoreDescriptions = [description]
    container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (description, error) in
        if let error = error as NSError? {
            DataController.isInitialized = false
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
        else {
            DataController.isInitialized = true
        }
    })

    mainContext = container.viewContext
    mainContext.mergePolicy = NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy
...
    backgroundContext = container.newBackgroundContext()
    backgroundContext.mergePolicy = NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy
...
```

Second we have the JSON data request (<- called every 30s on main thread)

```
static func request(performSave: Bool, name: String, completionHandler: @escaping (Bool, FooDataResponseResult, Error?) -> Void) {

    var urlComponents = URLComponents()
    ...
    var dataRequest = URLRequest(url: urlComponents.url!)
    dataRequest.httpMethod = "GET"

    let urlRequestCompletionHandler: (Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> Void = {
        (data, response, error) in
        guard let data = data, error == nil else {
            // Eroror handling
            return
        }

        if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {
            print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
            print("response = \(String(describing: response))")
        }

        let decoder = JSONDecoder()

        do {
            let responseObject = try decoder.decode(FooDataResponse.self, from: data)
            if responseObject.results.count>0 {
                DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
                    completionHandler(performSave,responseObject.results[0],nil)
                }
            }
            else {
                // No data
                }
            }
        } catch {
          // Error
        }
    }

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: dataRequest, completionHandler: urlRequestCompletionHandler)
    task.resume()
}
```

Third the `completionHandler` implementation. Here the `backgroundContext`  comes into play:

```
    let completionHandlerFooDataRequest: (Bool, FooDataResponseResult?, Error?) -> Void = {

    ...
        let taskContext = AppDelegate.appDelegate.dataController.backgroundContext

        taskContext.performAndWait {
        // all fetches on the taskContext
        // all managed Object creation on taskContext
        // all insert on taskContext
        // dont forget to save your changes
           taskContext.save()
        }
```

This only outlines how to accomplish the processing of JSON request, response handling and core data update in the background.